# quantlib: add handle to iborindex

Tags: programming, quantlib

I think this might be a very trivial question, but since I am pretty unfamiliar with C, this is a bit  of a problem for me.

I have created IborIndex somewhere (it is correctly working):

```
mspr = ql.IborIndex('Mosprime', ql.Period('3M'), 2, ql.RUBCurrency(), ql.Russia(), ql.Following,  True, ql.ActualActual()
```

Later I want to use it for cap pricing. I create some working yield curve handle:

```
curve_handle = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(mosprime3M.curve)
```

How do I pass it to the IborIndex? My solution is to recreate `ql.IborIndex` from scratch, using extracted parameters ( like `mspr.familyName()` ), but I believe there does exist a one-liner. Usual Python notation doesn't seem to work.  Could you please help?

Answer (score 4):

Pass a `ql.RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle` to the index constructor and then link a curve to it...

```
curve_handle = ql.RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle()
mspr = ql.IborIndex(
    'Mosprime', ql.Period('3M'), 2, ql.RUBCurrency(), ql.Russia(),
    ql.Following,  True, ql.ActualActual(),
    curve_handle)

crv = ql.FlatForward(2, ql.Russia(), 0.01, ql.ActualActual())
curve_handle.linkTo(crv)
```

or clone the index and pass a YieldTermStructureHandle

```
new_index = mspr.clone(curve_handle)
```

Comment: David, you are the best. Thanks a lot. Works exactly as I wanted.